# Python OpenVPN Script

Tags: python, subprocess, openvpn

I am attempting to write a python script for linux to start openvpn and have been running into a problem getting openvpn to start using subprocess.

I am using the following to start openvpn:

```
openvpn_cmd = ['sudo', 'openvpn', '--config', 'client.cfg', '--auth-user-pass', 'hmaauth.conf']
prog = subprocess.Popen(openvpn_cmd)
```

But I get the following error back from OpenVPN:

> Options error: --nobind doesn't make sense unless used with --remote

The config file is downloaded directly from the VPN service website prior to running the subprocess command, so I can't (and shouldn't have to) change anything in the configuration.

I've heard this can happen if you don't run with root privileges, but I'm already doing that...

**Does anyone have any suggestions as to why I am getting this error?**

I have a working shell script that starts openvpn using the following:

```
sudo openvpn --config client.cfg --auth-user-pass hmaauth.conf
```

Which should be exactly what I have in my python script.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: maybe try with full paths for openvpn and the configuration files?

Comment: Does the `openvpn` command work from command line? I can't see any python issue here, except that maybe you forgot to change to the right directory.

Comment: The python script sits in the same directory as the configuration files, so that shouldn't be an issue.  I'm scratching my head too, I can't see any issues with the python code.  The same command works fine from a shell script...

Comment: Gfei, when you run something as sudo, the environment variables are different.

Comment: Hmm, well I guess I'll try adding full paths when I get a chance later.  I've never run in to that issue before.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the problem here is that I'm dumb.  I was downloading a config file that didn't have the remote server for the VPN specified, now I understand the 'no remote' error.

Now that I have that cleared up we're good to go.